# How do I check if user is 'logged in' in a react component when using laravel authentication?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have setup laravel authentication in my website. It works very well but I want to know how I can check if a user is logged in when inside a react component and display his/her specific content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach I have used to solve the problem with checking if the user is logged in is to attach it in your main blade file as 'global data'. First set up your controller.

```
public function index()
{        
    return view('welcome')->with(["globalData" => collect([
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ]);
}
```

Then in your root blade file

```
<script>
    let globalData = "{!! $globalData->toJson() !!}";
</script>
```

Then you can access a user property anywhere in your components by refering to `globalData.user` and thus test if `user` is an object or null/empty.

---

## Example from a React project with version 15.4.2

### Controller

```
class GuiController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = [
            'projects' => $this->projects(), 
            'packs' => Pack::all(),
            'stimpack_io_token' => env('STIMPACK_IO_TOKEN'),
            'stimpack_data_url' => env('STIMPACK_DATA_URL'),
            'manipulatorData' => ManipulatorController::attachStartupData()
        ];
    }

    public function index()
    {        
        return view('welcome')->with(["data" => collect($this->data)]);
    }
```

### View

```
<body>            
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script>
        let data = {!! $data->toJson() !!};
    </script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>                
</body>
```

### Usage inside component

```
upload() {
    var compiler = new Compiler(this.props.engine);
    var compiled = compiler.compile();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("stimpack-io-token", data.stimpack_io_token);
        },
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this method but it says undefined variable globalData.

Comment: I formatted the code like this: <script>
    let globalData = "{!! $globalData->toJson() !!}";
</script>
and
public function index()
    {        
    return view('welcome')->with([$globalData => collect([
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ])
    ]);
    }
If I comment out the script tag in the root blade file, there is no error.

Comment: Good formatting, ill edit that. And you should be good just replace $globalData with 'globalData' in your controller. See the difference with my supplied example where it is a string and not a variable?

Comment: Awesome! I prefer front independent react code, using LocalStorage to store the auth code, but I didn't know the blade solution. Thank you

Comment: @Anders Thank You. This did work once I sorted out my routes. I can get the globalData on the view page by printing {{ $globalData }} but when I type globalData in any of my components, it says undefined. Do I need to pass it in a constructor and load the data from this variable?

Comment: No you should not have to do that. Can you post some code?  I added a real life example in the answer perhaps it can help you

Comment: @Anders Don't know what was wrong with it but now it is working perfectly. I am getting all the user details. Finding stuff for react laravel is a bit hard so I had to resort to stackoverflow for answers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Even though it seems like this is read-only information, are there any security risks associated with passing this information to the client-side?