# Laravel : Pass variable in web.php

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following in my `web.php`. It's a route to my React application.

```php
Route::get('/{path?}', function () {
    return view( 'welcome' );
})->where('path', '.*');
```

I would want of instead  `return view( 'welcome' );` to have

```php
return view('welcome')->with([
    "globalData" => collect([
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ]);
```

And I'm having a syntax error, perhaps a typo ?

Comment: You're missing another `])` as far as I can see

Comment: @ADyson I thought so, but I have this error `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `with()` correctly. If you want to pass an array like that, here's the correct syntax.

```php
return view('welcome', ['globalData' => ['user' => Auth::user()]]);
```

Or

```php
return view('welcome')->with('globalData', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
```

Or

```php
$globalData = ['user' => Auth::user()];

return view('welcome', compact('globalData'));
```

Maybe you should also take a look at [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers).

---

If you want to make use of this data only in JavaScript, you'll need to use both `json_encode()` to encode the array into a string and `JSON.parse()` to convert this json string into a proper JS object.

```js
var globalData = JSON.parse({{ json_encode($globalData) }}); // try with {!! !!} if it doesn't work.
```

Comment: Correct ! Thank you very much. I know I'm bit off topic but I have in my blade `<script> let globalData = "{!! $globalData->toJson() !!}"; </script>` and receiving the following error `Call to a member function toJson() on array` . If you have any idea I will appreciate it.

Comment: `toJson()` is a `Model` method. `$globalData` is a plain array. I'll add something in the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Here is what I'm following so you can get an idea. I think he got some code wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565500/how-do-i-check-if-user-is-logged-in-in-a-react-component-when-using-laravel-au

Comment: Thank you very very much. `{{ $globalData }}` is to display the value in the blade right ?

Comment: Yes. `{{ }}` echo whatever is inside.

Comment: It gives me this `.htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string`.

Comment: That answer you linked has the same typo ADyson pointed out in the comments. `toJson()` works if it's a Collection too but it's a bit unnecessary.

Comment: It was because I was outputin an array inside {{}}

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('welcome')->with('globalData', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
```

this is the syntext to use when you are using with for passing data.

see the example here : [How to pass data to view in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341792/how-to-pass-data-to-view-in-laravel)

Comment: Yes I missed `with->` as IGP said. Thank you !